# javascript - a function that makes a inner html with a video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video, attributes, innerhtml

Can someone pls fix this javascript function:

```
function open(file, poster) {
document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<video class='right' width='320' height='240' controls poster='" + poster + "'>
  <source src='" + file + "' type='video/mp4'>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>"
}
```

and just to be sure, when i call it, call it like this:

```
open(file.mp4, poster.png);
```

or like this:

```
open("file.mp4", "poster.png");
```

Comment: having a global function called `open` would override window.open - are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: You at the very least need to describe the issue you experience & show the html for `#video`. `open(file.mp4, poster.png);` is completely illegal without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

All you did wrong was the multiline string - not a good idea injavascript

```
function openVideo(file, poster) {
    document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<video class='right' width='320' height='240' controls poster='" + poster + "'><source src='" + file + "' type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>"
}
// call using the following format
openVideo('file.mp4', 'poster.png');
```

Comment: from some reason its not working, heres a test page: view-source:http://test.kepempem.com/STC/test.html

Comment: Your are not quoting, use `<body onload="openVideo('troubleturtle.mp4', 'FrameMyTV1083.jpg');">`

Comment: `call using the following format` - was there to re-iterate the point made by @AlexK. - "`open(file.mp4, poster.png);` is completely illegal without quotes. "